# How do I create an action to round the corners of images, given an unknown dimension?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing

I am very new to photoshop, and I am looking to create a reusable action that I can run on an image of arbitrary dimensions, leaving me with an image that has had the corners rounded by a radius of 50px.

I have watched a few YouTube tutorials on creating rounded edges, but none seem to be exactly what I'm looking for.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you just mean rounding the corners of a photo to create a simple transparent border, then something like this should work.

1. Begin recording a new action and give it a name you can easily find later
2. Unlock the background layer
3. Select All
4. *Select > Modify > Smooth*. Set the radius to 25 pixels, and choose With Effect at Canvas Bounds
5. Repeat step 3. This will round the corners more smoothly by another 25px giving a total radius of 50
6. *Select > Modify > Feather*. Set to 1px, and choose With Effect at Canvas Bounds
7. *Select > Inverse*
8. Hit <kbd>Delete</kbd> about 3 times.
9. Stop the recording

[image]